# How to add tags to RailsAdmin with autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, tags, rails-admin

I have been trying to add tagging functionality to RailsAdmin, but without success. I am using the following gems:

gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rails_admin_tag_list'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

The "rails_admin_tag_list" is adding tags, but it lacks the autocomplete functionality. I am trying to create a "custom field" / partial for the tags field, but I can't seem to get it right.

Has anyone succeeded in adding tags functionality to RailsAdmin, as well as autocomplete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An obvious solution I came up with, after posting the question is to implement tagging from scratch, using a has_many_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

RailsAdmin handles these relationships beautifully, and has autocomplete functionality by default.

However I am still looking for help/ideas on how to create "custom field" in RailsAdmin - I might need it for something else. Furthermore getting it to work with rails_admin_tag_list and autocomplete would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

i guess rails_admin_tag_list supports tag suggestion.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.models do
    edit do
      fields_of_type :tag_list do
        partial 'tag_list_with_suggestions'
      end
    end
  end
end
```